# New Answers (click to load) notification bar - Doesn't appear anymore

Tags: support, answers, notifications

For the past few days I've been posting answers on SO, I noticed that the orange bar at the top "X new answers has been made, click to load them" hasn't been showing anymore.

In the past I highly depended on them in case I am a tad slower that someone else and would post a similar answer.

**Browser:** Firefox 3.5.5

#### Steps taken

1. Open SO on new tabs (I open between 3-6 tabs)
2. One is the Recent Questions page, the other is a question opened from the recent page (doing this at a time where SO is the least active - around 10am GMT).
3. The question page was left there, refreshed the Recent Questions page
4. On the Recent Questions page I see a count of say 3 answers
5. Turn back to the question page
6. Wait for a while
7. The bar still doesn't appear.

Please look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start putting something in the "Your Answer" box the site picks up your attempt at an answer. It will then poll the question and see if any new answers have been added. This is around 30 second polls, and if it finds something, it will display the notification bar.

If you only load up the question but don't start an answer, then it won't poll, and you won't be told there are other answers.